# delayed startet audio file throws error on iOS html app

Tags: vuejs3, html5-audio

I play lottie files and mp3 files within a pwa app. sometimes the audio files start with a delay an I trigger the audi with a timeout.

```
<audio ref="audioPlayer4" crossorigin playsinline @ended="audioEnded" :volume="store.state.volume"> 
    <source src="/audio/11.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

For some reason I now have a problem playing a sound at a certain point via settimeout. I then get the following error on iOS mobile devices.

```
The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
```

On iOS this results in the error: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

```
setTimeout(() => {
          if (audioPlayer4.value != null){
            audioPlayer4.value.play();
          }
        }, 1050);
```

how to get around this?

Comment: Does your app meet any of the [audio autoplay conditions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability)?  I don't think the setTimeout function is a guaranteed workaround. Because of these standard restrictions you should introduce some kind of user interaction before attempting to play any audio.